# I don't have Source Code Pro font in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I want to use Source Code Pro font in PhpStorm.

I looked for it in `Settings > Font` but it doesn't exist in dropdown.

How can I add it here?

Comment: Install it OS-wide (so it can be used in any app) then look again. P.S. From what I remember in the past IDE reads list of fonts only once per session; so IDE restart might be needed to see updated list of fonts.

Comment: Is it available on your system? In case the font is not available on the system you [can get it here](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by checking show only monospaced fonts my problem is solved